# Xcode 12.2 Beta 3: ld: unknown option: -no_adhoc_codesign

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, ld, xcode12

Downloaded Xcode 12.2 Beta 3 and trying to compile my app. Getting the following linker error:

```
ld: unknown option: -no_adhoc_codesign
```

It looks like `-Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign` is being added to the linker flags.

**Where does this linker flag come from, and how do I remove it?**

I searched and grepped the entire app, but couldn't find this flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It looks like this comes from zld](https://github.com/michaeleisel/zld). Disabling zld fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Hey there Jason. Can you describe the process of 'disabling zld'? I'm assuming this may be something during the build process, but I'm not really sure. Any extra input?

Comment: zld is an alternate linker that you can use instead of the one packaged with xcode. If you haven't set up zld manually, you probably aren't using it.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue on released version of Xcode 12.2(12B45b). Resolved by updating "Command line Tools" setting in Xcode to use Xcode 12.2.
[Xcode Preferences Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDF7v.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on V12 and I performed- Clean the project and pod install should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can arise when build setting PRODUCT_NAME is empty for dependent library.